# Using \foreach to generate functions

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

I wish to plot a function based on collection of simple functions. For instance, the maximum of some functions:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[smooth, color=black] 
  {
     max( 2*x, 3*x, 4*x, 5*x, 0)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I generate this function using `\foreach`?

The following doesn't seem to work

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[smooth, color=black] 
  {
     max( 
        \foreach \k in {2,3,4,5}
           {\k*x, }
         0)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

as it gives the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.  
\foreach ...@empty \let \pgffor@assign@after@code  
                                              =\pgfutil@empty \let \pgff...  
l.164       };
```

Comment: Why not determine the max symbolically? For example, the maximum of the functions you've listed will always be 5x when x>0 or 0 when x<0, so you can just use `max(5x, 0)`.

Comment: I gave `2*x` etc only as a simple example. The real functions I have are more complicated, and their maximum changes with `x`, yet all have a similar form. A better example would probably be `sin(\k *x)`.

Comment: Yes, but my point is, whatever your actual functions are, consider finding their maximum symbolically. You can construct a piecewise function with `ifthenelse`. As far as I know, you can't use `\foreach` in a mathematical expression, so I'd suspect it's impossible to do what you want to do without implementing your function in TeX.

Comment: First, to do these sorts of calculations, you need to use \pgfmathparse etc.  (Note, (x,y,z) coordinates are automatically run through \pgfmathparse).

Comment: Second, where is x being defined?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have parametrised familly of functions ? A solution may have your convinence here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184944/expandafter-expandbefor-what-else

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
    f1(\t)  = 5-5*\t ;
    f2(\t)  = 4-2*\t ;
    f3(\t)  = 3-\t ;
    f4(\t)  = 2-.5*\t ;
    f5(\t)  = e^(\t-4) ;
    Max(\t) = max(  {f1(\t)},
                    {f2(\t)},
                    {f3(\t)},
                    {f4(\t)},
                    {f5(\t)}
%                   {f6(\t)},
%                   {f7(\t)},
%                   {f8(\t)},
%                   {f9(\t)},                   
                ) ;
        }
    ]

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymax=7]
  \addplot[color=black,smooth,samples=400] 
  {
    Max(x)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whit `egreg` answer here : 's [\expandafter, \expandbefor : what else?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184944/expandafter-expandbefor-what-else/184952#184952) :

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\Liste{\n-\n/(6-\n)*x}{5}

\bigskip    

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,samples=400]
   \Liste[\foo]{\n-\n/(6-\n)*x}{5}
  \addplot[color=black,smooth,samples=100] 
  {
    max(\foo,e^(x-4))
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be in the right direction. I'll try to understand the `\expandafter`, `\expandbefore` commands