# \expandafter, \expandbefor : what else?

Tags: macros, expansion

I have a macro that prints exactly what I want, but I can't use it nested in another one. As far as I understand it is because the fist one is not completely executed and commands from first macro mixt together with those from the second one.

How to proceed ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\makeatletter
\def\L@ste#1#2{
    \count255 = 1
    \loop   
    \def\n{\the\count255}%
    #1%
    \advance\count255 by 1
    \ifnum\count255>#2
    \else
    ,%
    \repeat
    }
\def\Liste#1#2{\L@ste{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb+\Liste{\n-\n/(6-\n)*x}{5}+

Prints exactly what I need :

\Liste{\n-\n/(6-\n)*x}{5}

\bigskip    

But I can't use it directly :

\verb+max(\Liste{\n-\n/(6-\n)*x}{5})+

produces errors ...

\bigskip    

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymax=7]
  \addplot[color=black,smooth,samples=400] 
  {
% can't use it here, Why ?
    %max(\Liste{\n-\n/(6-\n)*x}{5})
max(1-1/(6-1)*x,2-2/(6-2)*x,3-3/(6-3)*x,4-4/(6-4)*x,5-5/(6-5)*x)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense, sorry. For many reasons. One of them is that `\else` is not legal in `\loop`, but it's perhaps the least.

Comment: @egreg `Loop` seems to ignore that as it works well, the result is correct. I don't understand then what you mean. By the way, how to test `count255<=#2` as `<=` is forbiden and doesn't work ?

Comment: @egreg http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb08-2/tb18kabel.pdf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know that paper; but this has the original `\loop` macro.

Comment: @Tarass Your `\Liste` macro produces the instruction for **printing** what you'd like to feed to `max`; but you can't use it in the argument of `max`, because this wants the *functions*, not the instructions for printing them.

Comment: It is what I understand, my question is : is there a way to convert the printing instructions in printed instructions: I mean in something that `LaTeX` understands as typeset ? It works fine for `foreach` arguments, I did it several times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The loop via `\loop` is not expandable, because it contains assignments. For the same reason `\def\n{\the\count255 }` (BTW, note the space) is not expandable as advancing the counter via `\advance`.

`\Liste` could be implemented in an expandable way:

- Package `intcalc` helps in incrementing in an expandable way,
- `\n` needs to be exchanged by the number in an expandable way.

But it is much easier to construct a macro (also token register) that contains the expanded list. In the following example `\Liste` generates the list and stores the result in macro `\ListeResult`. The latter can be used in `max`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Liste}[2]{%
  \count@ = 1 %
  \let\ListeResult\@empty
  \loop
    \def\n{\the\count@}%
    \edef\ListeResult{\ListeResult#1}%
    \advance\count@ by 1 %
  \ifnum#2<\count@
  \else
    \edef\ListeResult{\ListeResult,}%
  \repeat
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Prints exactly what I need :

\Liste{\n-\n/(6-\n)*x}{5}
\ListeResult

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymax=7]
  \Liste{\n-\n/(6-\n)*x}{5}
  \addplot[color=black,smooth,samples=400] {max(\ListeResult)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Great ! thank you for explantions and for the solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can't feed `\Liste` to `max`, because it wants a syntactically correct list of functions, not the instructions for ***printing*** them.

Here's a working implementation; you must first compute the substitutions and define a macro to contain the list. Then you can use this macro in the argument of `\max`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Liste[3][]{%
  \def\Liste@temp{\@gobble}%
  \count@=\z@
  \loop\ifnum\count@<#3\relax
  \advance\count@ by \@ne
  \begingroup\edef\n{\the\count@}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\Liste@temp{\Liste@temp,#2}}\x%
  \repeat
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \Liste@temp
  \else
    \let#1=\Liste@temp
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Liste{\n-\n/(6-\n)*x}{5}

\bigskip    

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymax=7]
   \Liste[\foo]{\n-\n/(6-\n)*x}{5}
  \addplot[color=black,smooth,samples=400] 
  {
    max(\foo)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A new implementation with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addplotlist}{smO{1}mmO{}}
 {% #1 = * if printing
  % #2 = function to apply to the list
  % #3 = starting point, default 1
  % #4 = end point
  % #5 = list building function
  % #6 = options for addplot
  \cs_set:Nn \__tarass_process:n { ,#5 }
  \clist_set:Nx \l__tarass_process_clist
   {
    \int_step_function:nnnN { #3 } { 1 } { #4 } \__tarass_process:n
   }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    $\use:c{#2}(\clist_use:Nn \l__tarass_process_clist { ,~ })$
   }
   {
    \addplot[#6]{ #2(\l__tarass_process_clist) }
   }
 }
\clist_new:N \l__tarass_process_clist
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addplotlist*{max}{5}{#1-#1/(6-#1)*x}

\addplotlist*{min}{5}{#1+#1/(6-#1)*x}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymax=7]
  \addplotlist{max}{5}{#1-#1/(6-#1)*x}[color=black,smooth,samples=400];
  \addplotlist{min}{5}{#1+#1/(6-#1)*x}[color=red,smooth,samples=400];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The variable parameter is denoted by `#1`. The `*` version prints the obtained list.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is much harder to understand for me than Heiko's one. Could you please, on spair time, add some comments explaining the purpose of the different commands ? I am very interested in. Of course I'll add a bounty on it.